# how to fix "No route matches [PATCH]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am a newbie to ruby on rails. I was working on a project and run into an issue with a form. I am using devise for authentication. I have a user class which has admin and user roles. The devise generated add/ update methods for user is working properly. I am running into a 'No route matches [PATCH]' error when I am trying to create an edit page for the admins. here is the form I am using

```
<h4>Update Profile</h4>
 <%= form_for @user, :url => {:controller => "admin", :action => "update" }  do |f|  %>

<%= hidden_field_tag(:id, @user.id) %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field  :first_name , :class => "form-control"%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field  :last_name , :class => "form-control"%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field  :email , :class => "form-control"%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= f.submit "Update", :class => "btn btn-md btn-success pull-right" %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<%end%>

This is my controller method

```
def edit
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if request.post?
     if(@user.update_attributes(params[:first_name, :last_name, :email] ))
      redirect_to :action =>  "admin_portal"
  else
    render :action => "edit"
  end
end

end
```

I also have the route

```
get 'admin/update'
 get 'admin/edit'
```

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The point is: you are setting only `GET` from HTTP's methods, and for updates, you need a `PUT` or a `PATCH` method. 
There are some conventions when to use `PUT` or `PATCH`, but in your case, making a `PATCH` route would solve your problem as you said

```
patch 'admin/:1'
```

But, apparently you are writing yourself a route for every REST method, and Rails has a "helper" structure called `resources` that create all the REST methods for your.
You could create just one entrance on your `config/routes.rb` like:

```
resources :admins
```

and it would generate every route intended for the REST methods pointing for your `user_controller` and renamed as `admin`. Putting only that line of code, is be equivalent to write all these commands on your config/routes:

```
get 'admins', controller: 'admins', action: :index
get 'admin/:id', controller: 'admins', action: :show
get 'admin/new', controller: 'admins', action: :new
get 'admin/:id/edit', controller: 'admins', action: :edit
post 'admin', controller: 'admins', action: :create
patch 'admin/:id', controller: 'admins', action: :update
put 'admin/:id', controller: 'admins', action: :update
delete 'admin/:id', controller: 'admins', action: :delete
```

You can see more on [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). It has many useful advices on creating routes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `form_for @user` for persisted model it generates `patch`, and you only have `get` in routes. Change `get` to `patch`. More info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Igor. I just tried using patch instead of a get and now I get a different error. It says the update action is not found in the AdminController

Comment: Yeah, just realized, you need `patch 'admin/:id', to: 'admin#update'`